# Why I am getting wrong count() value in sparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I am using sparkSQL, have one column, whose total count is 1252226.

```
spark.sql("""select col1 from employee """).count()

output: 1252226 



spark.sql("""select distinct col1 from employee """).count()

output: null
        X 

 count for X = 288149
       IS NULL = 964077  


spark.sql("""select col1 from employee where col1 != 'a' """).count()

    output: 0
```

Here in last query( where !- 'a' ), why is it showing 0 records, it should show 1252226.

Comment: How do you know it should be 1252226? Are there no 'a' rows and no null rows?

Comment: `NULL <> 'a'` returns *unknown*, thus I would expect 288149 (if col1 actually contains 288149 'X')

Comment: yes @jarlh There is no 'a' rows and have null and X

Comment: @dnoeth in col1 its total count is showing 1252226, and 'X' is 288149